# PHP keeps leaking IP address

Tags: onion-services

I'm trying to setup a hidden service, I've tunneled my server though tor, however things like gethostbyname is leaking my real ip address, I have no clue why its doing that, while curl doesn't....

Is there anything I'm missing.

Comment: What OS? And do you run apache, nginx or something else? Does webbrowser also leak ip after it's been torified? ( with for example https://check.torproject.org )

Answer (score 1):

an answer is simple, not tied to PHP only :

1. Use 127.0.1.1, 127.0.1.2 etc dedicated localhost-*like* IPs for each of dedicated hidden services. Do **not** use 127.0.0.0/24 subnet at all - it will expose your localhost!
2. Use ISC bind for **all** dns lookups on a host. Pair it with Tor DNS port, and in a reverse zone assign xxx-dot-onion names to IP's from pt.1
3. As a backup for pt.2 use `/etc/hosts` file
4. In your service's webserver bind the server to IP's from pt.1 and suppy a corresponding hostnames to virtualhosts

That's it!